# Tortoise HG - Add a tag on commit

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

At the moment, I only know how to add a tag after a commit. This means that a get a second commit that just contains the tag. Is it possible to add a tag on commit?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No, because a tag is an entry in the `.hgtags` file at the root of your repository containing the changeset id and the tag name, and this file itself is under revision control.  The changeset id isn't known until the changeset is created, so tagging creates another changeset to check in the `.hgtags` file recording the tag for that changeset.

Answer (score 4):

According to mercurial wiki, it is impossible. Just like Mark said.
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Tag

But then, i just wondering. Why not mercurial ignoring the .hgtags file altogether ? just like it ignores .hg/ folder.
So mercurial won't include .hgtags everytime it's generating a changeset ID.

Would be great if .hgtags, .hgignores, etc is resides inside .hg/

Comment: I assume the reason is that you normally want to check in the .hgignores and .hgtags

Answer (score 3):

For my point of view, Hg tagging system is a bit messy because creating a tag changes the history and needs merging and committing even if no project file has changed. Tagging can burden a history graph very quickly.

I was used of SVN tagging which was done on a separate branch, which has the advantage not to change working branch history. Moreover, tagging can be done from any branch, because Hg takes tags from the .hgtags files on the heads of all branches.

The little script below creates a branch "tagging" and puts tags in it. It merges the current branch in "tagging" branch, so it's easy to see the changeset tag was done from (it especially avoids long refreshes when switching branch).

It can probably be improved, but it suits my needs.

I strongly recommend making a clone of your project before testing this script, in case it does not behave as you expect!

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function echo_red()
{
  echo -n -e "\e[01;31m"
  echo -n "$1"
  echo -e "\e[00m"
}
export -f echo_red

# Display the help and exit
function show_help {
    echo "Usage: $0 [hg_tag_options ...]"
    echo "    tags a version (current if not specified) in the 'tagging' branch."
    echo "    Options are the 'hg tag' ones, plus"
    echo "        -?, -h, --help  Show (this) help"
    exit 1
}

#  Parse the command-line arguments
function parse_args {
    for arg in "${commandline_args[@]}"
    do
        case "$arg" in #(
            '-?' | -h | --help )
                                show_help
                                ;;
        esac
    done
}

commandline_args=("$@") 
if [ "$commandline_args" = "" ]
then
    show_help
fi
parse_args

VER=`hg id | sed 's#\([0-9a-z]*\).*#\1#g'`
BRANCH=`hg branch`

# Check for clean directory
TEST=`hg st -S -q`
if [ "$TEST" != "" ]
then
    echo_red "Directory contains unresolved files !"
    exit 1
fi

hg update --check >/dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    echo_red "Directory contains unresolved files !"
    exit 1
fi

# Switch to tagging branch
hg update tagging >/dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "Creating new 'tagging' branch."
    hg update default >/dev/null
    hg branch tagging
fi

# Merge if changes detected
TEST=`hg diff -r $VER -X .hgtags --stat`
if [ "$TEST" != "" ]
then
    #take only the 'tagging' version of hgtags
    cp .hgtags .hgtags.bak
    hg merge -r $VER --tool internal:other >/dev/null
    rm .hgtags
    mv .hgtags.bak .hgtags
    hg commit -m Merged
fi

# Tag and Switch back to original
hg tag -r $VER $@
hg update $BRANCH >/dev/null
hg update $VER >/dev/null
```

**Example Usage:**

```
hg_tag.sh [-f] [-l] [-m TEXT] [-d DATE] [-u USER] [-r REV] test_v1_5
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can move the tag to a different changeset.

```
hg com -m "moving tag to this changeset"
hg tag 0.1 -f
hg push
```